# Best way to search march in an array of JavaScript Objects?

Tags: node.js, arrays, search, filter

I'm facing a challenge to match values within an array of JS objects. Let me give you an example,

```
var dynamicObjectArray = [
{Id: 1422859025, FromTime: "2023-02-12T19:00:00Z", ToTime: "2023-02-12T20:00:00Z"},
{Id: 1422859027, FromTime: "2023-02-12T18:00:00Z", ToTime: "2023-02-12T19:00:00Z"}
]
```

I need to find all **Id**s for **FromTime** or **ToTime** match with "2023-02-12T19:00:00Z"

Using a database, it can be done easily. But, here, I need to play an array of 100 objects max. Also, data will be dynamic. Can you please suggest me a way to achieve the goal using NodeJS.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the JS Date builtin constructor to compare dates instead of using the string directly.

Filter your matching objects, and map the ids.

You can do something like this.

```js
const dynamicObjectArray = [{
    Id: 1422859025,
    FromTime: "2023-02-12T19:00:00Z",
    ToTime: "2023-02-12T20:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    Id: 1422859027,
    FromTime: "2023-02-12T18:00:00Z",
    ToTime: "2023-02-12T19:00:00Z"
  }
];

const matchTime = new Date("2023-02-12T19:00:00Z").getTime();

const matchIds = dynamicObjectArray.filter(obj => {
  const fromTime = new Date(obj.FromTime).getTime();
  const toTime = new Date(obj.ToTime).getTime();
  return matchTime === fromTime || matchTime === toTime;
}).map(obj => obj.Id);

console.log(matchIds);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a suggestion, you can do something like this:

1. Create a function that takes as a parameter, the wanted Date
2. Create a variable containing an array where you will save all those "id's" that match your condition
3. Create a for loop
4. Create an if condition, that matches the following condition:

- if date exists on "FromTime" or exists on "ToTime", push to your "id's array"

5. Return your ids array

Here is the code implementation:

```
function filterObjByDate(TO_MATCH_DATE) {
  let ids = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < dynamicObjectArray.length; i++) {
    if (
      dynamicObjectArray[i].FromTime === TO_MATCH_DATE ||
      dynamicObjectArray[i].ToTime === TO_MATCH_DATE
    ) {
      ids.push(dynamicObjectArray[i].Id);
    }
  }

  return ids
}
```

That's it. If you have more question, ask me